# How to make child composite fill parent in swt

Tags: java, swt

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite childComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    childComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    Text text1 = new Text(childComposite, SWT.NONE);
    Text text2 = new Text(childComposite, SWT.NONE );

    Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Very loooooooooooooooooooooooong text");

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

This will produce something like this:

[image]

My question is how can i make my child composite fill the parent horizontally (be at least the same width that the label below).
I tried using something like this:

```
Composite childComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FILL);
```

... but that didnt change anything.

Also when the child is the same width as parent i want the text widgets to also fill the composite they are in but with different widths - for example the first is 20% and the second is 80%.
What possibilities should i check out to accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried `FormLayout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `GridLayout` you use `GridData` arguments to control `setLayoutData` methods to specify how the grid is filled.

You want something like:

```
  shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

  Composite childComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);

  // Composite fills the grid row
  childComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

  // Use 5 equal sized columns
  childComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, true));

  // First text fills the first column
  Text text1 = new Text(childComposite, SWT.NONE);
  text1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));

  // Second text fills the next 4 columns
  Text text2 = new Text(childComposite, SWT.NONE);
  text2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 4, 1));

  Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
  label.setText("Very loooooooooooooooooooooooong text");
```

Comment: Thats almost what i need but now i have the opposite problem - the input fields are now wider than the "Very lo...ong text".
It seems that every column has some kind of minimum width, because if i make 10 columns and put span of the first text 1 and span of the second 9 then it is wider than with 5 columns and span 1 and 4.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I think `Text` controls have a minimum size which you will struggle to get round with layouts.

Comment: Couldn't quite get it to work with GridLayout but it was close enough :) 
I checked out FormLayout and it was actually even better but ran into another problem i mentioned here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761207/is-it-possible-to-put-formlayout-into-gridlayout