# Is it possible to put FormLayout into GridLayout?

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to put a FormLayout composite into a GridLayout grid, but i get an exception. Am i doing something wrong or is it just not possible? Here is my code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class formlayout {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        GridLayout layout= new GridLayout(1, false);
        shell.setLayout(layout);

        Composite inputs = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        inputs.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        FormData fd1 = new FormData();
        fd1.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
        fd1.right = new FormAttachment(100,0);
        inputs.setLayoutData(fd1);

        Button button1 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button1.setText("B1");
        button1.setLayoutData(new FormData());
        FormData formData = new FormData();
        formData.left = new FormAttachment(20,0);
        formData.right = new FormAttachment(100,0);
        button1.setLayoutData(formData);

        Button button2 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button2.setText("B2");
        button2.setLayoutData(new FormData());
        FormData formData2 = new FormData();
        formData2.left = new FormAttachment(0,0);
        formData2.right = new FormAttachment(20,0);
        button2.setLayoutData(formData2);    

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
          if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
          }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

The exception i get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData
```

This is of course just a sample script to demonstrate the problem. Actually shell is defined lower in the code and it is set as GridLayout so i cant really change that but i still need to use FormLayout to acchive my goal with buttons.

Comment: The article [Understanding Layouts in SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) gives a good introduction in using layouts in SWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
Composite inputs = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
inputs.setLayout(new FormLayout());
FormData fd1 = new FormData();
fd1.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
fd1.right = new FormAttachment(100,0);
inputs.setLayoutData(fd1);
```

you are setting `FormData` in the layout data for `inputs`. The layout data is used by the layout specified for the **parent** of the control - in this case the parent is `shell` which is using `GridLayout`.

So when the grid layout for `shell` is doing the layout it is expecting all its children to have a `GridData` in the layout data, but you have `FormData` so the cast it is doing fails.

Specify `GridData` for the layout data of `inputs`, just use `FormData` for the child controls of `inputs`.